# How to add image texture to 3D asset in Xcode using SceneKit

Tags: ios, 3d, scenekit

I have a 3D model for a coffee mug which is in .dae format. Now what I need is - to place a logo (a png image) in on it. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

This isn’t really a Scenekit or IOS question. To apply a texture to a 3D model the model needs UV coordinates per vertex. The process of mapping a 3d model to a 2d texture is known as UV mapping ( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_mapping ) and is done in 3d software like Blender, 3D studio max and similar packages, *before* the assets (model and textures) are used in Scenekit.

That said, in this case, because a mug is largely a cylinder, you could perhaps get away with using a SCNCylinder (which automatically comes with UV coords) and using the image with the logo, *with a transparent background*, as a texture for the cylinder. And then scale and position the cylinder over the mug and add it as a child node of the mug.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your model in a node, yo can access the material trough the [geometry](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scngeometry) like this

```
node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = <put your image here>
```

with this you will replace the texture of your geometry, don't really know if thats you want.

Comment: I have a 3D model of a cup and i need to place a logo and do a realistic rendering in my iOS app using SceneKit

Comment: you need to add more details about it, but I think you can accomplish that way, also if you have the texture of the mug you can try to merge the logo with the mug texture (and place in the desired place of the texture the logo) and then re-apply to the model. maybe you can update your question with some other details and may help if you add a graphic example of what you want, or maybe what you have.